# Long running task in UI thread

Tags: ios, swift, macos, xamarin

I have a long running task that manipulates an NSMutableAttributedString.
That manipulation includes checking fonts, such as:

```
    bold = (pfont.FontDescriptor.SymbolicTraits & NSFontSymbolicTraits.BoldTrait) != 0;
```

and creating fonts to adjust text, such as:

```
    var fontmgr = NSFontManager.SharedFontManager;
    font = fontmgr.FontWithFamily(fontname,
                                          (bold ? NSFontTraitMask.Bold : 0) |
                                          (italic ? NSFontTraitMask.Italic : 0),
                                          5, size);
```

I dont want to freeze my UI thread while this is happening, so I am hoping to perform this manipulation in a background thread. Note that I am *not* touching any UI elements during this processing - just modifying the NSAttributedString.

You can do *some* manipulation of NSAttributedString in a background thread, but it seems that touching fonts is verboten as it raises an AppKitThreadAccessException.

So I need to run my manipulation in the UI thread, and I'm looking for a way to grab slices of CPU time. Ideally there would be a way to relinquish control periodically like the bad old days of cooperative multitasking - something like this:

```
    var paragraphs = myBigLongAttributedString.BreakIntoParagraphs(); // this is fast.
    foreach (var paragraph in paragraphs) {
        // do some work on the paragraph
        relinquish control
    }
```

or to add the paragraphs to a work queue that gets processed in the UI thread.

Many thanks for any ideas.

Cheers.

Paul

Comment: have you tried creating a copy of the existing NSAttributedString variable and apply the operation on it?

Comment: Hi Malav. Yes - that is exactly what I do - I grab a copy of the live string, pass that to the background thread where it gets processed. To modify the fonts inside the string, you need to create font objects, and that is where it goes awry. Most other NSAttributedString manipulations are fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - one more version of the code. This time with proper locking, and using ManualResetEvents rather than Task.Delay (testing shows it 20-40% more accurate).

```
/// <summary>
    /// Dispatch work items in the main UI thread while ensuring that the UI
    /// is not starved of processing time.
    /// </summary>
    public static class MainDispatcher
    {
        static ConcurrentQueue<Action> workList = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();
        static bool active = false;
        static object activeLock = new object();

        public static void RunAsync(Action action)
        {
            workList.Enqueue(() =>
            {
                //  Run the requested code, then request the next one (in a task, so the UI thread is not used)
                action(); _ = Task.Run(Next);
            });

            if (!active)
                Activate();
        }
        static void Activate()
        {
            //  We need a separate flag for starting the runner if active was false. We CANT use
            //  active, because it could change between the end of the lock and the Task.Run.
            //  We can't extend the lock because we cannot be locked when we start the task runner
            //  (that could cause a deadlock)
            bool start_runner = false;
            lock (activeLock) 
            {
                if (!active)
                {
                    active = true;
                    start_runner = true;   
                }
            }

            if (start_runner)
                Task.Run(Next);
        }
        public static void Clear()
        {
            workList.Clear();
        }

        static void Next()
        {
            Action p = null;
            //  Delay to ensure UI thread can process UI events
            //  Note that WaitOne on a manualresetevent is more accurate than Task.Delay(1) by about 20%-40%.
            new System.Threading.ManualResetEvent(false).WaitOne(1);
            //Task.Delay(1).Wait();   
            lock(activeLock)
            {
                active = workList.TryDequeue(out p);
                if (!active)
                    p = null;
            }
            try
            {
                if (p != null)
                    DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(p);
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways which can implement it , like **NSThread**, **NSOperation/NSOperationQueue** classes or **GCD**.

For example （using GCD）

```
using CoreFoundation;
```

```
DispatchQueue.GetGlobalQueue(DispatchQueuePriority.Default).DispatchAsync(() =>
{
  DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(() => { 

     //do something you want

  });
});
```

Comment: Lucas - GCD looks interesting. The docs dont mention it - do you need to make each DispatchWorkItem quite short to ensure the UI stays fluid? Or can I drop a long work item and the GCD will do some fancy switching? I'm guessing the former - in which case I can create thousands of DispatchWorkItems (one per paragraph) and watch for the last one to get completed.

Comment: Yep... works a treat. Can I ask why you had proposed nested async dispatching? In my case I didn't need it since I was already in a thread.

Comment: My code is just for demo , you could improve it in your case :)

Comment: Gotta say this isn't as good as I was hoping. I fire a few thousand very small tasks into the GCD as above. Each task takes 1-2ms. While those are being processed... the UI is completely unresponsive. I was expecting the UI to at least stay functional.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned above... using DispatchQueue to perform some processing doesn't really work because DispatchQueue seems to starve the UI if you throw a lot of work at it.

In more detail: I can break my processing down to several thousand very small work items (each taking 1-2ms). Executing those via:

```
DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchAsync(() => ProcessParagraph(para));
```

causes the UI thread to hang.
So I wrote an alternative - something that I could throw lots of jobs at and would run them while ensuring the UI activity continues. It seems to work, so I thought I'd post it here to see if its useful, and to ask for comments/improvements.

Basic idea is to ensure there is a 1ms pause between work items.

Using this class below, my UI stays completely responsive while the Main thread is working hard on my long set of tasks.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Dispatch work items in the main UI thread while ensuring that the UI
    /// is not starved of processing time.
    /// </summary>
    public static class MainDispatcher
    {
        static ConcurrentQueue<Action> workList = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();
        static bool active = false;

        public static void RunAsync(Action action)
        {
            workList.Enqueue(async () =>
            {
                action(); await Task.Delay(1); Task.Run(Next);
            });
            if (!active)
                Activate();
        }
        static void Activate()
        {
            active = true;
            Task.Run(Next());
        }
        public static void Clear()
        {
            workList.Clear();
        }

        static void Next()
        {
            Action p;
            if (workList.TryDequeue(out p))
                try
                {
                    DispatchQueue.MainQueue.DispatchSync(p);
                }
                catch { }
            else
                active = false;
        }
    }
```

Couple of notes:

- I appreciate I should mutex the test and set of the `active` flag - but for me its not required since I only pump work items into the queue from a single thread.
- I use DispatchSync so I can guarantee at least 1ms of delay between executions of the work items.
- Processing is slower overall, but the UI stays fluid so that's a worthwhile tradeoff. I could probably experiment with reduced Delays but that's not needed now.

Thanks to Lucas for the pointers that got me going.

Comment: Happy coding :)